# Building a report in SSRS, want to show a line ONLY when it is the last row of a group

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I am trying to build a report to only show specific notes below the LAST line in a grouping, but that grouping may only be part of a data set.

Quick example: I have a bunch of orders with a line number and a row number.  The report separates by line numbers already, but I do not know how to tell it to show  a line at the end of each section (the last row of an order/line number)

[image]

[[image][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJcBl.png)

In the picture, I would want a "notes" field to show after each of the bottom lines in the tables.

Comment: You should provide a dataset sample and a screenshot or a text-table example of your expected results in order to help you.

Comment: Just did, let me know if you need more.

Comment: What is the structure of your dataset? and share the rows or columns groups you have added if any.

Comment: Added a dataset picture.

Comment: Are the notes specific to Line_No or Line_Item_No?
If Line_No then it's a simple grouping matter, else you may need to employ the LookupSet() function.